# AdMob API and keywords

Tags: android, search, keyword, admob, ads

Does anyone manage to get relevant advertisement from AdMob server when setting keywords or search query ? My application runs on Android and I manage to retrieve ads from the AdMob server.

I try several solutions but they do not seem to work.

---

**Solution 1:** use the methods `setKeywords( String keywords )` or `setSearchQuery( String searchQuery )` from the AdView class and then, call `requestFreshAd()`. When a request is currently in progress, a call to `requestFreshAd()` generate the following message in log :

> *"WARN/AdMobSDK(2541): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are
>   requesting an ad right now already."*

.

Thus, I try to call `requestFreshAd()` when no request are in progress but it doesn't work anymore.

---

**Solution 2:** In the XML layout, use the attributes `myapp:keywords="myKeywords"` on the AdView element. This attributes is previously declared in the attrs.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

ADMob SDK will automatically request new add based on the set refresh rate. I think that the default is 60s. So, you don`t have to call `requestFreshAd()` at all. Run your app from from Eclipse, go to activity where the adds are, and watch logcat window. Periodically you will see that adds are fetched automatically, based on that refresh rate setting.
You can change that refresh rate on http://www.admob.com/my_sites and than clicking 'Manage settings' on an app, and 'App settings'. Also, you can simply set a refresh interval with the `refreshInterval` attribute on the AdView element in your layout XML file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you for the refreshInterval. However, I try to use it because the ad returns was not linked to keywords. I see that the AdMob API changed some days ago ; maybe they have corrected the keywords API (I hasn't tried it yet).

Comment: @TeddyBearFr - I haven't updated the admob code yet and was wondering what you thought about the code update?  Have you had any luck setting keywords and getting better results?  I have set keywords and am not getting results matching the keywords at all basically.  It's like adMob is just throwing ads up there and not paying any attention at all to my keywords.

Comment: @dell116 I haven't updated the AdMod code. Thus, I cannot tell you if this keyword issue has been solved.