# Admob errors, can't get ads to show

Tags: android, admob

I've been trying for days without any results to get my admobs running..
I have been following the tutorial on http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html but can't seem to make it work..

My java file:

```
// Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Manifest:

```
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.kai.custombutton"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
      <attr name="adSize">
          <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
          <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
          <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
          <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
      </attr>
      <attr name="adUnitId" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I've added the admob sdk 4.0.4 also..
If anyone have a working code I would be very pleased if I could use it or if anyone could help me out!

Comment: Why are you doing adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); ?  Having the adview in your layout and loading the layout should be enough. Important thing is that you have enough space for the banner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who needs a good tutorial on the newest admob sdk (4.0.4) look at this site: http://www.taiic.com/2011/04/27/admob-4-0-4-tutorial/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+taiic+%28App+Inventor+Info+Center%29

Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Mine works using this:

```
ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxadmobIDxxx");
LinearLayout layout =
            (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_admob_layout);

layout.addView(ad);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.setTesting(false);

ad.loadAd(request);
```

`ad` is a global, private `AdView`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your AdMob account.  Is your account receiving requests for impressions?  If it is receiving requests, then your code is fine.  It looks ok from my end, but I might be missing something.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687737/xml-or-java-keywords-in-android-for-admob) was one of my older posts when I was struggling with adMob.  It has my xml and java code that is currently working on my app.

If that's your real adUnit ID number in your code above, I'd get rid of it ASAP.  There's no need for the rest of the world to know that number!

Comment: ...you also might want to take a look at the DDMS output for whatever device you're sending ad requests from....if you see something like onFailedToReceiveAd( No ad to show), then adMob is receiving your requests for impressions, but your current campaign settings are not triggering an add to be returned to the client.

Comment: Oops.. thanks!
Tried the other way which haphazard mentioned and it works now! Or it's counting on the admob site but the banner won't show up..
Just wondering, how long does it take for the admob site to update new ad requests from my app?

Comment: Login to your admob account, click the "sites and apps" tab, go down to your app...and click "Manage Settings."  Once your in the "Manage Settings" section for your app, click the "App Settings" tab, scroll down...and you can set the refresh rate.  You can also do this in code via XML or java.